# OOP and functional programming together in Kotlin (Design)

Tags: android, oop, functional-programming, architecture

I recently started with Kotlin for android development. It is object oriented but also supports functional constructs like lamdas, monads, etc..

I am thinking of leveraging the benefits of both the worlds. I'd like to design the layers of my app as follows,

------ **OOP** ----------- || ----------------- **Functional** -----------------------------------------------------
View -> ViewModel -> Usecases -> Repositories -> Data layer/DataSources -> Network

**Some guidelines I'm thinking to follow:**

1. State of my app will be stored in the viewmodel layer and displayed in the view layer.
2. Functional layers will be stateless containing only the pure functions.It translates the provided input to the desired output. They need not worry about the environment it is running and also should run context less.
3. No Android components should enter the functional layer. It is dedicated only for business logic
4. Viewmodel layer contains application logic and presentation logic. State is exposed as Livedata in this layer
5. Views subscribe the livedata and updates the view when notified.
6. Usecases are business logic units
7. Viewmodel will pass the immutable state object copy to the usecase layer.
8. The communication from viewmodel to usecases will be offloaded to background thread and reverse communication in UI thread that way I don't have to worry background threads touching my Views.
9. UsecaseExecutor should be used to execute any usecase since it is one which takes care of offloading using coroutines
10. All pure functions should be unit tested
11. Respositories abstract the data sources
12. Network layer will contact the rest services and Data layer receives the response JSON/XML , parses and provides back either the corresponding models or Error.
13. All functions that can throw errors should have return type as Either< Failure,Success > monad
14. Failure should be a sealed class

I'd like to know the flaws in this design or somethings I have not taken care of and Some best approaches to be followed.

Comment: don't forget about Dagger

Comment: Thanks for your input! :) Yes, I'll be using dagger for DI

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use functional features in kotlin you need to add a functional library like arrow because kotlin core does not provide many of the basic functional features like Either monad for example like you say in point 13, optics, and some others. 
Other than that I think the design is good